# How to import multiple excel files present in a folder and apply given algorithm to each of them in R?

Tags: r, excel, import

I have multiple excel files in multiple folders each file needs to be imputed separately with an algorithm, so I want to import data as per file and impute on them using the algorithm one by one but separately without merging any data

I have tried using the readxl library

```
library(readxl)

file.list <- list.files("C:/Users/srich/Downloads/Course Project Datasets/Incomplete Datasets Without Labels/4-gauss", pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_xlsx)
```

But I am only getting list of files present in that folder, I want each file data to load in the environment for imputation.

Sorry if I was vague in my question as I am new to R, just a couple of days of experience. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need them in the `.GlobalEnv`,  leave them as a list. To impute try `df.imp <- lapply(df.list, impute_function)`. If the function has more arguments, `df.imp <- lapply(df.list, impute_function, arg1 = value1, arg2 = value2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Could be made simpler (though less efficient) to do this in a for loop.

For example,

```
file_vector <- list.files(path = "A:/data folder")  
csv_list <- file_vector[grepl(".csv",file_vector)]  
for (i in 1:length(csv_list)){

data <- read_csv(paste("data/", csv_list[i], sep=""))  
#whatever imputations that you want
write.csv(data, paste("data/","out", csv_list[i], sep=""))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will import data from multiple sheets in multiple Excel files.  Try it, and feed back.

```
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename) { 
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename) 
  x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X)) 
  names(x) <- sheets 
  x 
} 
files <- list.files(path = "/directory/in/question/", 
                     pattern = "*.xlsx",
                     full.names = TRUE)
out <- lapply(files, read_excel_allsheets)
names(out) <- basename(files)
```